# Filtering by an ID that is part of a JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query wthat has many joins. The data that comes back is correct:

```
SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  cmba.field_id,
  cmba.attr_val,
  cmba.upd_dtt,
  cmba.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb
INNER JOIN contract_member_brg_attr cmba
  ON (cmb.item_id = cmba.item_id) where  cmb.item_id=8086
UNION
SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  ca.field_id,
  ca.attr_val,
  ca.upd_dtt,
  ca.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb 
INNER JOIN contract_attr ca 
  ON (cmb.contract_item_id = ca.item_id) 
WHERE ca.field_id IN (413) and cmb.item_id=8086
UNION
SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  91,
  m.item_name,
  m.upd_dtt,
  m.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb
INNER JOIN contract_attr ca
  ON (cmb.contract_item_id = ca.item_id
  AND ca.field_id = 234)
INNER JOIN mfr m
  ON (ca.attr_val = m.item_pk);
```

I am trying to filter for a specific item_id:

[image]

I have tried WHERE clauses all over the place with different aliases.

Where can I add a filter to this query so that I can return only a specific item_id in this select statement?

Comment: You need to add a where clause to both queries. Simply add "where  cmb.item_id=8086" to the second query and you should be good to go.

Comment: Oops I guess there are three queries. Given that I would go with the answer proposed by EoinS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your whole query a sub-query and filter on that:

```
select * from 
(SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  cmba.field_id,
  cmba.attr_val,
  cmba.upd_dtt,
  cmba.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb
INNER JOIN contract_member_brg_attr cmba
  ON (cmb.item_id = cmba.item_id) where  cmb.item_id=8086
UNION
SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  ca.field_id,
  ca.attr_val,
  ca.upd_dtt,
  ca.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb 
INNER JOIN contract_attr ca 
  ON (cmb.contract_item_id = ca.item_id) 
WHERE ca.field_id IN (413) and cmb.item_id=8086
UNION
SELECT
  cmb.item_id,
  91,
  m.item_name,
  m.upd_dtt,
  m.upd_usr
FROM contract_member_brg cmb
INNER JOIN contract_attr ca
  ON (cmb.contract_item_id = ca.item_id
  AND ca.field_id = 234)
INNER JOIN mfr m
  ON (ca.attr_val = m.item_pk)
) a
where item_id = 'whatevs';
```

[Here is an example to demonstrate](http://rextester.com/JRGPQ56089)

Comment: It looks like the item_id=8086 clauses are not needed inside the inner select. But the rest worked great!